# Using a method from my class to another's class object in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

lets assume that I have two list classes the one is a double queue list and the other one is a FIFO list. Those two classes have their own que/deque/set/get methods, but is there any way to be able to use a method from the FIFO class for both a FIFO object and a double queue one?

```
class FIFOque {
public void put(object ob){//puts an item in the top of the queue }
public object remove(object ob){//removes the object from the top of the queue}
}

class DoubleQueueList{
public void DoubleFrontPut(object ob){//puts an item in the front of the queue }
public void DoubleBackPut(object ob){//puts an item in the back of the queue }
public object removeFront{//removes the object from the front of the queue}
public object removeBack{//removes the object from the back of the queue}
}
```

My question is, if there is a way to be able to use the method put for both an

```
FIFOque and a DoubleQueueList object, for example :
FIFOque ob1=new FIFOque();
DoubleQueueList ob2=new DoubleQueueList(); 

ob1.put(object ob);//puts ob in the top of the queue
//this is what I want to know if it is possible
ob2.put(object ob);//puts the ob item in front/back of the DoubleQueueList
```

If there is a way to use the method of the FIFO class to put an object to the front/back of the DoubleQueueList

Comment: By using inheritance/interfaces? It's a rather vague question as is, please add some code to demonstrate what exactly you mean (and what you have tried doing)

Answer (score 0):

Write an interface. As the name suggests it will provide only the interface of the common functions. In your methods you can then replace all uses of e.g. `FIFO` with the interface and then it will accept both implementions.

```
public interface Container {
    public void set(int i, E val);
    public E get(int i);
    // ...
}
```

In both of your classes inherit from the interface:

```
public class Deque implements Container {
    // ...
}
```

And then use the interface instead of a specific implementation in your methods.

```
public void doSmthWithAContainer(Container c) {
    E e = c.get(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide on this:

> `//puts the ob item in front/back of the DoubleQueueList`

Do you want to put it at the front or back? You must choose one of the two. After you've chosen, you can add a method like this:

```
public void put(object ob){
    DoubleFrontPut(ob);
    // or
    DoubleBackPut(ob);
}
```

Then you can call `put` on a `DoubleQueueList`.

You can also create a new interface and make both queue types implement it:

```
public interface Putable {
    void put(object ob);
}

class FIFOque implements Putable{ ...

class DoubleQueueList implements Putable{ ...
```

Now you can do this:

```
Putable ob1=new FIFOque();
Putable ob2=new DoubleQueueList(); 

ob1.put(obj1);
ob2.put(obj2);
```